# bones moving around and misbehaving

Tags: armature

[![hello!

i want to pair a bone to another bone. either it will in no way at all whatsoever connect or it moves the whole bone to the wrong end of the parent bone. the arms only wants to connect/parent to the hip, i cant make them parent to the top/shoulders

i cant parent/connect the head to the shoulder either, everything i try either moves the bone to the wrong location or just wont connect at all..

thanks for any help :)

[image]

Comment: Make the bone sit on the "_naughty chair?_"

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are having issues is because your spine isn't a single unified chain. Normally, the spine bones start at the hips and move up the back and ends in the head. Legs and arms can then be placed relative to those bones.

Add in a bone on the ground below the neck and extend it up so it ends in between the spine and head. This will be your root bone. Parent the spine bone, the arm bones, and the neck bone to the root bone. Be sure to uncheck the deform option in the bone tab on the root bone.

Comment: Ps its a turtle haha thats why it looks so wierd! And thanks for the reply it works fine now!

Comment: Yeah I figured it was something like that. Don't forget to mark the question as answered. Thanks and You are welcome.